# Setting Request Priority Volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am trying to set the priority of my requests using the Volley library in Android. I cant find out how to set the requests priority.

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,"feed URL",volleyListener, volleyErrorListener);
pe.requestQueue.add(request);
```

Any Ideas on how I would do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The library unfortunately isn't fully fleshed out yet.  To set priority for a request you need to extend the request and override getPriority().  For your example I would create a new class that extends StringRequest and implements getPriority() (and maybe a setPriority() as well, so you can programmatically change priorities in different requests).

```
private Priority mPriority = Priority.LOW;

@Override
public Priority getPriority() {
    return mPriority;
}

public void setPriority(Priority priority) {
    mPriority = priority;
}
```

`Priority` is an ENUM from the `Request` class.

Comment: Turns out imagerequest has Priority.LOW set already but you answer works. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, ImageRequest has it already, but StringRequest does not, and the Request class doesn't provide a method to manually set it. Volley works well as is, but if you want to tailor it to your own uses custom classes are still required.

Comment: Volley supports four levels of priority - Low, Normal, High and Immediate.

Answer (score 11):

Heres a quick way to set a priority,

```
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,"feed URL",volleyListener, volleyErrorListener) {
        @Override
        public Priority getPriority() {
            return Priority.IMMEDIATE;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a much better way of doing a simple thing like just changing the priority.

Comment: is this will set the priority also I am little bit confused can you clarify please..

Answer (score 0):

With Kotlin :

```
val stringRequest = object : StringRequest( Request.Method.GET, url, 
    { response -> Log.i("Response", response) }, 
    { error -> Log.i("Error", error) } ) 
    { override fun getPriority(): Priority { return Priority.HIGH } }
```