# android Volley - Request.setSequence is useless?

Tags: android, android-volley

Going through the Volley source code, it appears the setSequence method of a Request is useless. In RequestQueue.add(Request) method, it appears that Requests are added in the original sequence they are added in as this would line would indicate:

```
request.setSequence(getSequenceNumber());
```

(getSequenceNumber() just returns an incremental counter).  Is there any way to order Requests or should I hack Volley even further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Priority`

```
private Priority mPriority = Priority.LOW;

@Override
public Priority getPriority() {
    return mPriority;
}

public void setPriority(Priority priority) {
    mPriority = priority;
}
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641108/setting-request-priority-volley).

Comment: I understand about using Priorities. However, there are times when I don't want to mess around with Priorities but still be able to jump the queue for Requests, so to speak. Take the case of a few long running requests in Fragment A, the user goes to Fragment B, I'd like all of Fragment B's request to be processed first. I can set them to Priority.HIGH but then what happens when user goes to Fragment C, D, E, etc. I'm out of "Priorities".

Answer (score 2):

You can't give request an order, but you can make them run one after another. For this you need to implement your own *RequestQueue*.

Here is sample which demonstrates how to make all your requests execute in the same order, in which you added them to queue, since it uses single thread execution.

```
// Copied from Volley.newRequestQueue(..); source code
File cacheDir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), "def_cahce_dir");

String userAgent = "volley/0";
try {
    String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
    userAgent = packageName + "/" + info.versionCode;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
}

if (stack == null) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) {
        stack = new HurlStack();
    } else {
        // Prior to Gingerbread, HttpUrlConnection was unreliable.
        // See: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html
        stack = new HttpClientStack(AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(userAgent));
    }
}

int threadPoolSize = 1; // means only one request at a time
RequestQueue queue = new RequestQueue(new DiskBasedCache(cacheDir), network, threadPoolSize);
queue.start();
```