# Setting Priority for Volley ImageLoader

Tags: android, android-volley

I have created a Image loader using Google volley library. My problem is that i don't know how to set priority to each requests. Could some one help me with the same ?The below shown is the code. Where should i set the priority ?

```
 Main Activity

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ListView list;
ImageLoader mImageLoader;
ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    mImageLoader = MyVolley.getInstance(this).getImageLoader();
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, mImageLoader);

    list.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

}
```

}

```
      Adapter class

                  public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
NetworkImageView nImgView;
ImageLoader mImageLoader;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, ImageLoader mImageLoader) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mImageLoader = mImageLoader;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return ImageLinkArray.imageUrl.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_adapter_layout,
                parent, false);
    }

    nImgView = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.networkImageView);

    nImgView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    nImgView.setImageUrl(ImageLinkArray.imageUrl[position], mImageLoader);
    return convertView;
}
```

}

```
      MyVolley class


       public class MyVolley {

private static MyVolley mVolleyInstance;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private static Context mContext;

private MyVolley(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();


    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
            new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<>(
                        ImageLinkArray.imageUrl.length);

                @Override
                public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    cache.put(url, bitmap);
                }

                @Override
                public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return cache.get(url);

                }
            });

}

public static synchronized MyVolley getInstance(Context context) {
    if (mVolleyInstance == null) {
        mVolleyInstance = new MyVolley(context);
    }
    return mVolleyInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        // use the application context
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext
                .getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {

    getRequestQueue().add(req);

}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    return mImageLoader;
}
```

}

Comment: check out this SO Question. It may help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641108/setting-request-priority-volley

Comment: This is for string request right ?? am using an image request

Comment: If you look at the source code of ImageRequest here (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageRequest.java), you can see that the "default" priority is low. Create your own "ImageRequest" class (copy and paste), but set the priority to high...

Comment: is the any provision for setting different priorities to different requests

Comment: I guess you can add it as part of your constructor?

Comment: This adapter doesnt work ?? which code to be written inside image loader ?? no use of overriding getpriority in myvolley class ??

Comment: See addToRequestQueue argument. Inside Request class just implement set/getPriority. And just set priority when needed. Request object which added to queue must be customized. And before add it to queue you have to call setPriority(priority).

Comment: you can not do it because you are using NetWorkImageview if you want to use NetWorkImageview and changing priory you must change volley source code.

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
private Priority priority = Priority.HIGH;

StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.GET, Const.URL_STRING_REQ,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                hideProgressDialog();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
        }) {
    @Override
    public Priority getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

};
```

from [androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

**UPDATE**

Here is another workable [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)

to set the priority of a `Request` you have to add some code snippet to `AppController` class of the example

convert

```
public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}
```

to

```
public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    com.android.volley.Request.Priority pr = req.getPriority();
    pr = com.android.volley.Request.Priority.HIGH;
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}
```

and make it workable by calling the method with some extra parameter

Comment: This is for string request right ?? am using an image request

Comment: Actually Request<T> req is list of requests right? How can i set to a particular request high ??

Comment: make it as your own way. i see `Respose` added to queue via `AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);` as `JsonArrayRequest` take it as `StringRequest` i said before and use it to `movie.setThumbnailUrl(StringResponse);`

Comment: Now it's easier to set `Priority` via my first answer

Comment: But its image am dealing with

Answer (score 0):

Check out [ImageRequest](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/blob/master/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageRequest.java) class from Volley. It created for Image loading by Google developers, you just have to extend it and implement setPriority().

```
// default priority
private Priority mPriority = Priority.LOW;

@Override
public Priority getPriority() {
    return mPriority;
}

// priority setter
public void setPriority(Priority priority) {
    mPriority = priority;
}
```

`Priority` is an ENUM from the `Request` class.

from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641108/setting-request-priority-volley)

Each request has `getPriority()` method inherited fro Request class. This method used inside Volley `RequestQueue` to determine request priority inside this queue.

To use this your Request just have to override getPriority() and you have to implement `setPriority()` method inside request as shown above.

Comment: ok i have created a priority class and extended imagerequest  and coded the following one. fine...but how to set priority to each request??

Comment: You don't have to create Piority class it's already designed and used inside Volley. Each request has getPriority() inherited from Request class. You just have to use it by override and implement setPriority() for your request. RequestQueue will read this priority by invoke getPriority().

Comment: So should i implement the above code in my singleton class itself?? just the above code would do??

Comment: Above code must be part of your request class. It shows you how to implement setRequest() with class variable which hold request priority. getPriority() will be used by Volley itself to done this scheduling for you.

Comment: Actually am getting mad with this :( . I ll post the code just tell me where to insert this ??